# Troubleshooting CRONIC/CRON causing 'No such file' Error

Tags: linux, cron

I've got a couple of Cron jobs setup that I have piped through Cronic so that I only get emailed if there is an error.

Whenever I run the command in a terminal without Cronic the command executes correctly with no errors.

```
root $nice -n19 cronic /usr/local/bin/dirperms/mediadrive-dir-perms.sh
```

However ever now and again I'll get an email from CRON with an error as follows.

```
nice: cronic: No such file or directory
```

I'm having trouble working out why this error is occurring.

Comment: Set the full path of cronic in cron and command line. Cron run in very limited PATH. And probably you do not have this command in shell PATH

Comment: And check that you've spelt it correctly - here, it's called `chronic`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've added the full path /usr/bin/chronic and installed chronic. It seems like there's actually two wrapper scripts that can be installed cronic and chronic. The latter being install via `sudo apg-get install moreutils`.

Thanks for your help @RomeoNinov and @toby-speight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed chronic via

```
sudo apt-get install moreutils
```

Then adapted CRON command to include the full path to chronic. ie.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/chronic COMMAND
```